# bootbox 4.4 how to alert with different button label

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, popup, bootbox

i see in bootbox v3 documentation you can change the label by using below method
bootbox.alert(str message, str label, fn callback)  Custom button text, callback invoked on dismissal,

However on version 4.4 this method does not seem to work, how can i get to use a custom button label on alert message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override the text for any dialog, using the `buttons` option (which does require you to use an options object to setup your dialog). For example, here's a custom alert:

```js
$(function() {
  bootbox.alert({
    message: 'I have a custom OK button',
    buttons: {
      ok: {
        label: 'Right on!'
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

For confirm and prompt, you can override `confirm` and `cancel` as buttons.

Comment: i wish they had this in documentation

Comment: hi i have another questions for you. perhaps you can help me, i am trying to have confirm button in bootbox.confirm come before cancel button. I have to do this across all bootboxes so perhaps i can configure it once rather than each individual element?

Comment: There isn't currently a way to swap the order of the buttons. You could modify the source if you really need a specific order to the buttons.

Comment: you have idea where is it?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "it."

Comment: haha. you said 'could modify the source', i meant which source are you talking about?

Comment: The confirm dialog's buttons are specified here: https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/blob/master/bootbox.js#L321 - swap the values in the middle if you want the order always reversed.

Comment: great appreciate your help alot

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
bootbox.alert({ 
   size: 'small',
   message: "Your message here…", 
   callback: function(){ /* your callback code */ }
}).init(function(){ 
    $('.btn.btn-primary').text('Custom Text')
});
```

> From the docs: `bootbox.init(function): Allows the user to supply a function to be called when dialog gets initialized.`
>   http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-public-methods